# VirtualBox crashes by USB spikes

Tags: usb, virtualbox

My two *Windows* machines use the same keyboard and mouse with a simple *USB* switch.

One *Windows* machine hosts a *VirtualBox* 7.0.12 server and several *Linux* distributions as *VBox* clients.

When I switch the keyboard and mouse back to the *VirtualBox* system, I often encounter a `VirtualBoxVM.exe - Application Error` with details such as `The instruction at 0x00007ffCD0EF6DB2 referenced memory at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. The memory could not be read.` The *Linux* client still accepts the keyboard and mouse. It works, except that the shutdown hangs. Clicking OK on the *VBox* error message shuts down the client completely together with the *VBox* server software. The hosting Windows system has no problem.

It could be a sensitive reaction of *VBox USB* emulation software to electrical spikes from switching on *USB* wires.

Do you got any idea to improve my installation, avoid these spikes, or harden *USB* emulation of *VBox*?